# Why doesn't Jest see the function call?

Tags: express, jestjs

I have a class with the **login** method:

```
import authService from "../service/auth";

class AuthController {
  async login(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const { email, password } = req.body;
      const token = await authService.login(email, password);
      res.cookie("token", token, {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
      });
      return res.status(200).json();
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  }
}

export = new AuthController();
```

And the test:

```
import AuthController from "./auth.controller";
import authService from "../service/auth";

describe("AuthController.login", () => {
  it("If it turned out to get a token, then a call should occur res.status(200).json()", () => {
    const next = jest.fn();
    const req = {
      body: {
        email: "email@example.com",
        password: "1234",
      },
    };
    const res = { cookie: jest.fn() };

     jest.spyOn(authService, "login").mockResolvedValue("t0ken");

    AuthController.login(req, res, next);

    expect(res.cookie).toBeCalledWith("token", "t0ken", {
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is that Jest claims that res.cookie **is not called**.

[image]

But when debugging, you can see that the call is happening:

[image]

If I comment out:

```
const token = await authService.login(email, password);
```

and I will enter the value of the token constant in:

[image]

The test will be passed.

I assume that I am incorrectly spying on the asynchronous function `await autoservice.login(email, password)`. Can you tell me where I'm wrong and why my test doesn't work?

Comment: _Timing_ is why. But don't test controllers like this, don't mock what you don't own.

Comment: What do you mean @jonrsharpe
? How do I test controllers correctly? Suggest your own option

Comment: At the _integration_ level, rather than with test doubles of Express objects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What does it mean at the integration level? Is this testing a controller call, without covering it? Give me a link to an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was only one problem -AuthController.login is an asynchronous method `async login(req, res, next)` , and I wrote a
synchronous test:

`it('If it turned out to get a token, then a call should occur res.status(200).json()', () => {test...}`

Therefore, the correct test will look like this:

```
import AuthController from "./auth.controller";
import authService from "../service/auth";

describe("AuthController.login", () => {
  it("If it turned out to get a token, then a call should occur res.status(200).json()", async () => {
    const next = jest.fn();
    const req = {
      body: {
        email: "email@example.com",
        password: "1234",
      },
    };
    const res = { cookie: jest.fn() };

    jest.spyOn(authService, "login").mockResolvedValue("t0ken");

    await AuthController.login(req, res, next);

    expect(res.cookie).toBeCalledWith("token", "t0ken", {
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
    });
  });
});
```

[image]